# Using combine package to articles with authblk

Tags: combine, authblk

I am trying to put together a small confenerence proceedings. There are participants from many diffirent institutions so I used the `authblk` package. The result is rather satisfactory. But then I need to combine all of articles in one file for which I use a `combine` package witha following preamble:

```
\documentclass[11pt, packages, book]{combine}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,graphicx,url}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[affil-it]{authblk}
```

The titles of articles in my combined document are still present, but author names and affiliation disappears. I have tried to add or remove `\usepackage[affil-it]{authblk}` in separate files and to turn on and off the `packages` option for `combine` but the only effect I've got is that than `authblk` is not included in the main preamble, but the `package` option is on, an author and affiliation is displayed for the first article, but not for the rest.

Is it possible to somehow use these packages together?